# Passing 'slow' parameter to toggle action

Tags: jquery

So [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v5KCE/) is a show/hide toggle button that works just fine. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v5KCE/1/) is the same exact code, except that I passed the `'slow'` parameter to the `.toggle` action. Why does the button's value toggle correctly in the first example, but not the second? Does passing the `'slow'` parameter to the `.toggle` action somehow cause the `:visible` pseudo-class to return true?

Comment: use callback function of toggle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#toggleButton2').click(function () {
    $('#disclaimer').toggle('slow', function () {
        if ($('#disclaimer').is(':visible')) {
            alert('hide');
            $('#toggleButton2').val('Hide');
        } else {
            alert('Show');
            $('#toggleButton2').val('Show');
        }
    });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/v5KCE/5/)

SAME BUT SHORT

```
$('#toggleButton2').click(function () {
    $('#disclaimer').toggle('slow', function () {
        $(this).is(':visible') ? $('#toggleButton2').val('Hide') : $('#toggleButton2').val('Show')

    });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK FOR SECOND ATTEMPT](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/v5KCE/7/)

Comment: It's actually not the same, your first example throws popups, the second one achieves the desired result, but, thanks!

Comment: alert are just to show that this time callback function called , anyways i am happy its works for you .

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193405/jquery-toggle-and-if-visible)

Use the `.toggle()` callback on complete.

*Code example from the other question*

```
$("#moreOptions").slideToggle('slow', callbackFn);

function callbackFn(){

     var $link = $("#lnkMoreOpt");

     $(this).is(":visible") ? $link.text("Less Options «") : $link.text("More Options »");


}
```

Please, use search bar and google it a bit before asking. Nevertheless, hope this helped!

Comment: Please, don't rudely assume I didn't spend time using search bar and Google. Seriously. I looked at a good 6-8 potential duplicates and spent decent time investigating before I posted. Folks like yourself give this site an annoying, elitist feel.

Comment: Searching `jquery toggle :visible` gave me an answer on the third search result. Excuse me if I insulted you by asking kindly to search harder next time, but after seeing that many questions that can be answered by simple search, every day I'm just trying to encourage people in harder investigation to keep the site cleaner and more efficient.

Comment: You didn't "kindly ask" anything, you talked down. If you had "kindly asked" that would have been great. Believe me, I'm all for keeping the place tidy and efficient, but sometimes a dupe gets through. Like I said, I spent decent time and didn't turn up squat. It's not like I'm asking lame subjective questions about "which framework is better for my site" ya know?